# Kibana Visualization from multiple Elastic Search Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I have a requirement to find the numbers of mobile applications registered by the customer. The Elastic Search index is designed as below (Mobile App in one index, Customers in one index and the association between both in 3rd index). When I created the Kibana Indexpattern for these 3 indices together, it does not provide meaningful/valid set of fields to query them.

### mobile_users

```
{
"_index": "mobile_users",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "mobileuser_id1",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
  "userid": "mobileuser_id1",
  "name": "jack",
  "username": "jtest",
  "identifiers": [ ],
  "contactEmails": [ ],
  "creationDate": "2020-09-29 09:18:36 GMT",
  "lastUpdated": 1601371117354,
  "isSuspended": false,
  "authStrategyIds": [ ],
  "subscription": false
  }
}
```

### mobile_applications

```
{
"_index": "mobile_applications",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "mobileapp_id1",
"_source": {
"appDefinition": {
"info": {
"version": "1.0",
"title": "TEST.MobileAPP"
},
"AppDisplayName": "TEST.MobileAPP1.0",
"appName": "TEST.MobileAPP",
"appVersion": "1.0",
"maturityState": "Test",
"isActive": false,
"owner": "mobileappowner",
"creationDate": "2020-09-24 11:21:44 GMT",
"lastModified": "2020-10-13 11:58:22 GMT",
"id": "mobileapp_id1"
}
```

### registered_mobile_applications

```
{
"_index": "registered_mobile_applications",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "mobileuser_id1",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"applicationId": "mobileuser_id1",
"mobileappIds": [
"mobileapp_id1", "mobileapp_id2"
],
"lastUpdated": 1601371117929
}
}
```

Can you advise if there is any way to get the count of registered applications for the given customer?

Answer (score 0):

it's Elasticsearch, not Elastic Search :)

given each of your document structures are dramatically different, it's not surprising you can't get much meaning from a single index pattern

however there's no way to natively count the values of an array in a document in Kibana. you could create a scripted field that should do it, or add that as a separate field during ingestion